# Finding the highest values a and b from an array

Tags: c++, search, sorting

I struggled a short while to make this work, so I'm wondering if there are any smarter ways for finding the highest of two values per array element? Uh, hard to explain by words, but by code its easy:

Data (random):

```
    (a) (b) // a and b are both positive values.
    10  0.5
    13  10.8
    8   0.123
    9   0.123
    17  0.3
    17  0.4  <- must find this
    17  0.1
    0   0.13
    0   0.5
```

Code:

```
int max_a = -1;
float max_b = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < total_values; i++){
    if(values[i].a > max_a){
        max_a = values[i].a;
        max_b = -1; // reset
    }
    if(values[i].a == max_a){
        if(values[i].b > max_b){
            max_b = values[i].b;
            found_id = i;
        }
    }
}
```

So far it seems to work. But is this the most efficient way of doing this? (without changing the for loop; must loop linearly like that)

**Edit:** Some notes: I use std::vector for my arrays. The code should work with any struct given to the vector, only 2 of the elements from that struct will be used for value checking. **Edit2:** Values cannot have negative values, thats why there is initial -1 values set to mean "not set".

**Edit: My test code:**

```
struct valuestruct {
    int a;
    float b;
    // this could have more values than just two. still, only two values are tested.
    // using shortest struct as possible to save memory for testing.

    valuestruct(int a, float b) : a(a), b(b) {}
};

bool operator<(const valuestruct &v1, const valuestruct &v2){
    return (v1.a < v2.a) || ((v1.a == v2.a) && (v1.b < v2.b));
}


void test_speeds(){
    // initialize array values:
    int total_values = 10000000; // = 80megs ram
    vector<valuestruct> values;
    for(int i = 0; i < total_values; i++){
        values.push_back(valuestruct(random(0,1000), random(0.0f,100.0f)));
    }

    int found_id = -1;
    // dummy stuff for preventing loops optimized off:
    int ids = 0;
    int out_id1 = -1;
    int out_id2 = -1;
    int out_id = -1;

    // Loki's solution:
    float t1 = microtime();
    if(total_values > 0){ // prevent crash accessing empty array.
        for(int dummy_repeat = 0; dummy_repeat < 100; dummy_repeat++){
            valuestruct max = values[0];
            for(int i = 1; i < total_values; i++){
                if(max < values[i]){
                    max = values[i];
                    found_id = i;
                }
            }
            out_id = found_id;
            ids += found_id; // dummy
        }
        out_id2 = out_id;
    }
    float speed1 = microtime()-t1;

    // Keith's solution:
    float t2 = microtime();
    for(int dummy_repeat = 0; dummy_repeat < 100; dummy_repeat++){
        int max_a = -1;
        float max_b = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < total_values; i++){
            if(values[i].a > max_a || (values[i].a == max_a && values[i].b > max_b)){
                max_a = values[i].a;
                max_b = values[i].b;
                found_id = i;
            }
        }
        out_id = found_id;
        ids += found_id; // dummy
    }
    out_id1 = out_id;
    float speed2 = microtime()-t2;

    clock_t t3 = clock();
    for(int dummy_repeat = 0; dummy_repeat < 100; dummy_repeat++){
        std::vector<valuestruct>::iterator find = std::max_element(values.begin(), values.end());
        found_id = std::distance(values.begin(), find);
        out_id = found_id;
        ids += found_id; // dummy
    }
    clock_t speed3 = clock() - t3;

    // Output:
    // Lokis: 6166.7ms
    // Keith: 3932.1ms


   // Timing on Loki's machine (using 1000 dummy iterations)
   // Compiled uisng g++ -O3 (replaced microtime() with clock())
   // Times are in seconds (result is the value of ids)
   Loki:  12.814812000 Result: 53500000
   Keith: 12.885715000 Result: 53500000
   Max:   12.832419000 Result: 53500000
}
```

Comment: Do you have max_bounds for either a or b? That is other than max_int?

Comment: @blufox, no other bounds than the values cant be < 0. both of the values wont exceed 1000000, im sure about that, if that matters.

Comment: I was wondering if you could use some thing like (a << 20) + b > (a' << 20) + b' as the comparison perhaps?.

Comment: @blufox, no no no... this must work for any datatype. basically im just finding better if-structures there. if possible.

Comment: I was thinking, if the `a` was float value, should i compare equality? I heard that same value in float can be represented in many ways or something like that, so equality wont always work...

Comment: This is the wrong site for this type of question. Best to ask on stackoverflow.

Comment: @LokiAstari, wait... what? im confused. what exactly is this site for...? i read the FAQ and i chose this site according to that.

Comment: @Rookie: This site is for review of working code. What you are asking for fits better on stackoverflow. and because of the higher traffic there you are likely to get better answers. The best solution is use [`std::max_element()`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/max_element.html) which would have come up very quickly over there.

Comment: @LokiAstari, my code works. By the way, max_element() doesnt do what i intend to do; i need to find index, not the values.

Comment: @Rookie: That is what max_element() does. It returns you an iterator (points at the element). Converting this to an actual index is trivial (see [`std::distance()`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/distance.html)). But if you need that you have other parts of your design that need to be worked on.

Comment: @Rookie: PS. You need to add to your question: 1) You are actually looking for the index. 2) The types of values (in C++ the type is the **most** important thing in a question and you are missing this. We do not know the type of `values` or the types held by `values`.

Comment: @Rookie: Code. Add code. English description of what you did is not enough. If you could show `compilable code`. Then we can start dissecting it for real.

Comment: When I run these I get exactly the same time (which is what I expect as the optimizer will turn them into the same code). What you are probably experiencing is cash warm up. The first algorithm warms up the cache which then helps the second algorithm. Also with optimizations turned on both of these take less that a second so that is not really much of a test. Optimizations off they take 10S.

Comment: Added a version that uses std::max_element to you test. Please run again. Probably 10,000 iterations. May want to increase the array size to something big

Comment: PS. I had to add a line to print `ids` or it was optimized out. So I printed the `ids after each loop. But in all my tests the difference between the three methods is insignificant (at less than 0.1%).

Comment: @LokiAstari, it seems like that my compiler options were weird. i had "only inline" for inlining functions... now i set to "any suitable" (Q:will it also inline the functions with inline command in them?) and yours is actually faster o_O ! but still, i cant use your code because its depending on the size of the struct being same as the tested variables.

Comment: @Rookie: Modern compilers (if not over-ridden by their user) will completely ignore the keyword inline (in term of in-lining). Their internal algorithms for choosing what to inline are much more sophisticated than what a normal program would use. As a result the compiler is much more accomplished at correctly deciding what to inline than a human. Note: Let it decide.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is just normal search for a max pair using [lexicographical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) ordering.

The issue with your code is that, it is linear O(n). While for a single use, this might be the best way, if you have to do it repeatedly, it would be better to build a priority queue [O(n)] with the comparison operator defined as pair compare, and then extract the top. (Even better if you can build the priority queue as you receive the elements.)

The pair comparison is derived directly from the definition

```
(a,b) ≤ (a′,b′) if and only if a < a′ or (a = a′ and b ≤ b′).
```

However you have mentioned the constraint that the loop shouldn't be changed. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: The loop cannot be changed because i dont want to add any more complexity there, keeping it simple; i can later optimize it myself. I will probably optimize this by quadtrees (these objects are in 2d world); i would still have to loop linearly, but that doesnt hurt much on performance.

Answer (score 1):

#### Real SOlution

```
typedef  std::pair<int, float>       Value;
typedef  std::vector<Value>          Values;

Values   values;
// Initialize all values;

// Then.
Values::const_iterator find = std::max_element(values.begin(), values.end());

// Want the raw index number for some strange reason.
int     index = std::distance(values.begin(), find);

// Note if you insist on using arrays rather than vectors then the C++11 version
//      works with vectors and arrays exactly the same way:
Value* find = std::max_element(std::begin(values), std::end(values));

// But if you insist on using arrays but are stuck with C++03
Value* find = std::max_element(&values[0], &values[size]);
```

#### Review of code

Neither of this is a minimum value.

```
int max_a = -1;
float max_b = -1;
```

So if your data happens to be all negative it will fail.

Unless there is some space concerns I do not see the point in using float. Prefer double the extra precision is usually worth it.

Why did you use two variables to hold the max. This is sort of an indication that you are looking for the max in each column separately. This is not the case so you should have a max value object.

```
Value   max = values[0]; // Initialize with first element.
```

OK. This is always going to be a linear algorithm O(n) as the data is not sorted. But prefer pre-increment `++i` over post increment. Technically there will be no difference for POD types (like int) but it is a good habit to get into for when you start using other types to iterate across the array.

Personally I hate such short variables names. But I know other like it for looping. The problem is that if the loop gets to any non trivial size the looking for all occurrences of `i` becomes a pain the arse. It is much easier to spot a longer variable name.

```
for(int i = 0; i < total_values; i++){
```

All this is way to complex.

```
    if(values[i].a > max_a){
        max_a = values[i].a;
        max_b = -1; // reset
    }
    if(values[i].a == max_a){
        if(values[i].b > max_b){
            max_b = values[i].b;
            found_id = i;
        }
    }
```

- You don't need a `found_id`. If the container is empty then you will not find a max.
- Otherwise use the first element to initialize the max.
- The loop over the other elements (ie starting at 1)
- See below on how to do the test in one condition.

Algorithm should look like this:

```
    Value max   = values[0];
    for(int loop = 1; loop < size; ++loop)
    {
        max = std::max(max, values[loop]);
    }
    // Modified based on comments. To get index use:
    Value max   = values[0];
    int   index = 0;
    for(int loop = 1; loop < size; ++loop)
    {
        if (max < values[loop])
        {
             index = loop; 
             max   = values[loop];
        }
    }
```

Now all you need to do is define the relationship between elements. By default `std::max()` will use the `operator<` to do comparisons but you can define your own comparison operator if you want a non standard way of determining max.

If The type of `Value` (which holds your int/float) pair is actualy typedefed to `std::pair<int, float>` then this is the default behavior.

```
 // It would be equivalent to this
 bool operator<(Value const & lhs, Value const& rhs)
 {
      return     (lhs.first < rhs.first)
             ||  ((lhs.first == rhs.first) && (lhs.second < rhs.second));
 }
```

Comment: Will this work? I need to find the array index, not the array values. Interesting solution though!

Comment: @Rookie: It already does that. std::max_element returns an iterator the max element. Which can be the index if you are using raw arrays (which is bad idea use a vector).

Comment: Unfortunately your code is twice as slow as the code made by Keith. I didnt test your distance() solution yet, though, but im not sure will it even work; I should also mention that i cant use std::pair here, because my struct is larger than just a pair, and the code should work with any struct. PS. i do use vectors.

Comment: @Rookie: If you think my code is twice as slow as anything then **you** are doing something wrong. The  STL algorithms are very efficient. So add to your question what you wrote and how you tested it. so we can point out your mistakes.

Comment: @Rookie: If you use vectors then that should be part of the code you have in your question!

Comment: @Rookie: You have two values. What is this new thing about a structure. You are obviously missing much more from your question that you need to add.

Comment: I added my compileable code (all you need to add is the random() function, i can provide that too if you need, though).

Comment: Now when i set the optimizations correctly, I'm confused, why is your code faster? Even when i increase the struct size to 200 bytes, its still faster! Why? It's basically the same code as Keith's is, except your comparisons are inverted, could that be the reason? BTW, why did you invert your comparison operators, and why does it even work correctly, im not sure why it works...

Comment: @Rookie: My algorithm should on average by no faster than Keith's. What you are probably seeing are differences caused by other parts of the hardware. Cache warm up affects. memory fetch stalls caused because their are other programs running on the computer. etc. That is why you should run the application on significant large data sets and over sufficiently large number of times to try and average out these affects. Update the size and loop count so they run for like 500 seconds. I bet you will see that they flip flop on which is better (also the difference will be less than 1%).

Comment: I've tried everything, i changed the order of the code execution, and i ran it multiple times, it still is faster. i dont have any programs running that would explain the speed differences, and even if i did, it would mean i would be using 99.99% of 4 CPU cores to have such an effect you described, but im not... can you explain why is it faster to copy 200 bytes struct than 2 variables...?

Comment: @Rookie: Have you **seeded** the random number generator to make sure you get different numbers each time (the default action will to produce the same set of numbers each time you run the application). The actual shape of the data could be affecting the results. But if you want an opinion you need to post code that I can read. English description of code is worse than useless as English is in-precise so we both make assumptions that will be different.

Comment: PS. You are running a very complex OS on the machine. Expecting that to have no affect on the timmings is neive. The OS is always using memory and the bus and all sorts of things in the back ground. The effect of the OS on causing cache misses can affect timing results drastically thus is why you need to run it over several minutes to make sure the affects on both timings average out to the same.

Comment: I already posted the code as far as i know. I used the same random seed for each time of course, why would i change that, i also tested with different random ranges, they did affect the performance, so the data was working correctly. caching? i dont know, why it would take many seconds if it "cached" the results, and why it fails on the other code right after it? I tested it now 100 times (ran for 10mins), and every each time yours was faster. That cant be a coincidence of my OS doing always something at that precise moments 100 times in row?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(values[i].a > max_a || (values[i].a == max_a && values[i].b > max_b))
{
        max_a = values[i].a;
        max_b = values[i].b;
        found_id = i;
}
```

or...eliminating max_a and max_b

```
if(values[i].a > values[found_id].a || (values[i].a == values[found_id].a && values[i].b > values[found_id].b))
    {
            found_id = i;
    }
```

Comment: Your latter code isnt right. How could it, when it doesnt remember the previous value? (i tested it and it doenst work). Your first code works so far, im not sure why though.... need to think more.

Comment: I'm surprised, your first version is 30% faster.

Comment: second one doesn't try to remember it just uses the index location of the highest value and compares new values against that,  never tested it though